# If $a$ and $b$ both commute with $[a,b]$, then $(ab)^n = a^nb^n[a,b]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Assume $a,b \in G$ for a group $G$ and assume
>
> 1. $a$ commutes with $[a,b]$ and
> 2. $b$ commutes with $[a,b]$
>
> (defining $[a,b]:=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$). For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $$(ab)^n = a^nb^n[a,b]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

(*Note:* The original post ommitted the $a^nb^n$ on the right hand side; hence many of the comments in the post...)

Since, $a$ and $[a,b]$ commute, we know

$$(a[a,b])^n = a^n[a,b]^n$$

Similarly, since $b$ and $[a,b]$ commute, then

$$(b[a,b])^n = b^n[a,b]^n$$

From these two findings, $[a,b]^n$ can be isolated so that

$$[a,b]^n = a^{-n}(a[a,b])^n = a^{-n}([a,b])^n$$

But after this point, I get stuck. Any suggestions on how to go about this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be something missing here - the statement in the $n=1$ case is $ab = [a,b]^0 = e$, which isn't right.

Comment: Moreover, if we assume $a,b$ commute, then for any fixed positive integer $n$, the stated claim reduces to $(ab)^n=1$, which need not be true.

Comment: As the other comments point out the statement is false. What is true is that $(ab)^n = a^n b^n [b,a]^{n(n-1)/2}$, assuming $a$ and $b$ commute with $[a,b]$.

Comment: You need to define $[a,b]$.

Comment: @quasi and all other commenters, I apologize for my poor choice of wording. The problem is supposing two things 1.) $a$ commutes with $[a,b]$ and 2.) $b$ commutes with $[a,b]$. To shorten this, I used the word "both" which may have sounded like $a$ and $b$ commute, but that isn't what I intended. I will edit the statement of the problem now.

Comment: That wasn't what quasi was saying. The issue quasi was highlighting is one I mentioned parenthetically about the abelianization: if $a$ and $b$ *also* commute with each other (an *additional hypothesis... e.g., take $b=e$), then it is clear your formula cannot be correct as written.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh I think I see the issue now. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wrong formula, that's why you are not getting it.

I will use the convention that $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, so that $xy=yx[x,y]$. Under the assumption that $[a,b]$ centralizes both $a$ and $b$ the formula is identical for the convention $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, as I will show at the end.

The correct formula is:

> If $[a,b]$ commutes with both $a$ and $b$, then $(ab)^n = a^nb^n[b,a]^{\binom{n}{2}}$ for all integers $n$, where $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ for any integer $n$.

Note what you are missing: <strike>you are missing the $a^nb^n$ factor preceding the commutator (which one is clearly missing, since the images in $G^{\rm ab}$ should still satisfy the identity!)</strike> (**Note:** Corrected later...) And also you have the commutator backwards.

**Lemma.** If $x$ and $y$ commute with $[x,y]$, then $[y,x^n] = [y,x]^n$ for all integers $n$.

*Proof.* This holds for $n=1$. Assuming it holds for $k$, we have
$$[y,x^{k+1}] = [y,x^kx] = [y,x][y,x^k]^x = [y,x][y,x^k] = [y,x][y,x]^k = [y,x]^{k+1},$$
and if $[y,x^n] = [y,x]^n$, then
$$[y,x^{-n}] = [x^n,y]^{x^{-1}} = [x^n,y] = [y,x^n]^{-1} = [y,x]^{-n},$$
as desired. $\Box$

Above, we are using the standard [commutator identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Identities_(group_theory)) $[a,bc]=[a,c][a,b]^c$ and $[a,b^{-1}]=[b,a]^{b^{-1}}$.  Note that this implies that if $[a,b]$ commutes with $a$ and $b$, then since $[b,a]=[a,b]^{-1}$, we have $[a^r,b^s]=[a,b]^{rs}$ for all $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$. (In fact, the commutator bracket is a bilinear map on $G/Z(G)$ when $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$.)

**Proof of the formula.**

We prove the formula by induction on $n$ (you can also prove it using [commutator collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_collecting_process)).

The equation holds for $n=1$, since $\binom{1}{2}=0$. Assuming that $(ab)^n = a^nb^n[b,a]^{\binom{n}{2}}$ for $n\gt 0$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
(ab)^{n+1} &= (ab)(ab)^n \\
&= aba^nb^n[b,a]^{\binom{n}{2}}\\
&= aa^nb[b,a^n]b^n[b,a]^{\binom{n}{2}}\\
&= a^{n+1}b[b,a]^nb^n[b,a]^{\binom{n}{2}}\\
&= a^{n+1}bb^n[b,a]^{n+\binom{n}{2}}\\
&= a^{n+1}b^{n+1}[b,a]^{\binom{n+1}{2}}.
\end{align*}$$
So the equation holds for all positive integers. Finally, for $n\gt 0$,
$$\begin{align*}
(ab)^{-n} &= \Bigl((ab)^n\Bigr)^{-1}\\
&= \Bigl( a^nb^n[b,a]^{\binom{n}{2}}\Bigr)^{-1}\\
&= b^{-n}a^{-n}[b,a]^{-\binom{n}{2}}\\
&= a^{-n}b^{-n}[b^{-n},a^{-n}][b,a]^{-\binom{n}{2}}\\
&= a^{-n}b^{-n}[b,a]^{n^2-\frac{n^2-n}{2}}\\
&= a^{-n}b^{-n}[b,a]^{\frac{n^2+n}{2}}\\
&= a^{-n}b^{-n}[b,a]^{\frac{-n(-n-1)}{2}}\\
&= a^{-n}b^{-n}[b,a]^{\binom{-n}{2}},
\end{align*}$$
as desired. $\Box$

The other convention, where $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ would have $xy=[x,y]yx$. But if $[x,y]$ is assumed to commute with $x$ and $y$, then $yx(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)=xy=[x,y]yx = yx[x,y]$,
so we have that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. Thus, both conventions will lead to the same formula under this assumption.

In short, <strike>you are missing the factors $a^nb^n$, and</strike> (corrected later) your commutator is backwards.

Comment: Thanks for an easy-to-follow and self-contained answer! I must have copied down the formula incorrectly. Flipping the commutator seems to fix everything!

Comment: @DavidC.Huang the major error is the missing $a^nb^n$, though...

Comment: Oh my goodness, I didn't even realize my major typo until now! I totally meant to include the $a^nb^n$. I feel so silly; I see what you mean now. Thank you

Comment: For those of us that tuned in during the 9th inning, we only see the corrected statement and not the original incorrect one making the comments a bit moot, however this was an interesting post and nice detailed proof (@ArturoMagidin)